# Storage size of struct hash_desc desc; isn't known

Tags: linux-kernel, sha, linux-kernel-headers

I am trying to invoke the SHA-1 algorithm using the Linux kernel driver. And the code that I am referring to has used the header file *linux/crypto.h*. The code uses a `struct hash_desc desc;` structure in the code which I thought was declared in the header file *crypto.h*. However when I looked for it, it was never initialized.

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/crypto.h> /* for sha1 */
#include <linux/scatterlist.h> /* for sha1 */

struct scatterlist *sg;

struct crypto_hash *tfm;
struct hash_desc desc;
void *ptr;
```

In the above code block, when compilation, it only throws an error at hash_desc but I checked and crypto_hash was also not declared or initialized in any of the header files yet there is no error in that line.
The error I am getting is that storage size of "desc" isn't known.
I tried declaring it in the header file *crypto.h*. Here is what I added in the header file,

```c
struct hash_desc desc;
u32 flags;
```

I don't really know what this is but this is what read through various sources. I thought that u32 will declare the size for the struct but that was not the case and it is still showing the same error, but now in both the code and the header files.

Comment: It's unclear how you try to invoke that. The error you see comes from the compiler meaning that the **definition** of the respective data type is absent.  What you added to the header file is non-sense. Do you understand how the C language source code works? Btw, since you haven't supplied kernel version it's also not clear how old it's. There is no `struct hash_desc` in the entire kernel source tree as of today (v6.8.y, v6.9-rc1), you need to understand what you are doing.

Comment: `invoke the SHA-1 algorithm using the Linux kernel driver` You want to call a linux kernel driver from userspace and that driver will somehow calculate sha-1 for a specific string? Or do you want to calculate sha-1 from the code inside a linux kernel driver?